# Are there still reasons to use class components if starting a hooks-enabled project?

Tags: reactjs

I'm starting a new project that's based on React >16.8, where Hooks are now available and stable. I've played around with them and really like what they offer, and would like to adopt them as much as possible in my project. My question is.. how much? Is there any reason for them to not be 100%?

Since functional components are now  offering the full arsenal of functionality that class components do, [are faster](https://medium.com/@trueadm/in-react-16-functional-components-are-quite-a-bit-faster-than-class-components-1afca4931d7c), are much easier to write and much easier to read, are there still reasons to use class-based components?

Comment: You don't, it's just a better and cleaner way. All class functionalities can be done with stateful functional components. see this https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-react-to-do-app-with-react-hooks-no-class-components. A complete app without classes

Comment: @its4zahoor That isn't true. [This FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#do-hooks-cover-all-use-cases-for-classes) lists some features that aren't implementable in functional components, even with hooks (at least not yet).

Comment: Yeah, but this is much closer to Stateful functional components. If you want something that isn't possible with hooks then there is no choice other than classes. Depends on needs.

Comment: Exactly. So not _everything_ can be done with stateful functional components then. You are disagreeing with yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the time of writing this, there are only a few small edge cases not covered by functional components using hooks (see [this FAQ](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#do-hooks-cover-all-use-cases-for-classes)) such as `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate` and `componentDidCatch` lifecycle methods. These are planned in a future hooks update.

Aside from those, every other feature of classical components can be rewritten in functional components that use hooks.

Classical components allow inheritance, but I personally don't consider component inheritance as part of the list of classical component features because it has been [strongly advised against](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#so-what-about-inheritance) since the beginning of React, as it goes against the design pattern React was built to accomplish.

Overall, after a few more updates to the hook feature, all classical components will be entirely rewritable as functional components that use hooks.

Answer (score 0):

You will need classes if you want inheritance, or want a component with common functionalities and extend it as needed. Other wise hooks provide a better and cleaner, easy to read, faster way to do almost all class functions.

Check this [To-Do App](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-react-to-do-app-with-react-hooks-no-class-components) with out using any classes.

Comment: "better and cleaner" is actually opinion based. Class are also easy to read. Inheritance is almost not used in React and not advisable. You can use HOC to create components with common functionalities.

Comment: @Sulthan I completely agree. Extending components goes against one of the main reasons React was built in the first place. HOC is the way to go. I've never even seen React code that extends other components.

Comment: @Adam, I am not aware of HOC, so i use inheritance. Can you help me know about HOC?

Comment: Googled and found it, Higher Order Components. I will learn about it. Thanks

Comment: @its4zahoor See [this official article](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html) about the difference between HOC and inheritance, specifically the bottom where they recommend against component inheritance.

Comment: "If you want to reuse non-UI functionality between components, we suggest extracting it into a separate JavaScript module." I have a reusable form component, I use it in my projects. It contains all the commons like handleChange, validations and input renderers etc. Works fine for me.